# In SQL Server, REPLACE function is not working properly when I use to replace with 1 space

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replace, sql-server-2008-r2

```
select 
    replace(WBSElem, appProj, '') AS WBSElement, 
    replace(WBSElem + '#' + Descrip, '', '') as Descrip,
    * 
from 
    SAP_sFTP_DB.dbo.MMHE_PS_WBS 
where 
    appProj = '1.13T0117' 
order by
    RecID asc
```

Here second replace is working fine, but the 1st replace is not working properly where I have above 100 records to change. I am getting output like nothing happened for 1st replace function. Can anybody help me?

Comment: You are not giving space here, you give empty. You have to give ' ' instead of ''.

Comment: i gave ' ' two single coats..

Comment: what is the use of second replace function? You can use concat function

Comment: No one can debug your code without knowing the contents of the various columns used. And phrases such as "not working properly" do not mean anything to someone that cannot see your data or your entire query. Help yourself by providing a script that demonstrates your problem and your expectations. Your second replace usage makes no sense - replacing an empty string with an empty string does what?

Comment: In your first replace, there may be white spaces leading or trailing  in `appProj` that fails the matching. So try using `ltrim` and `rtrim`

Comment: + jophab thanks sir.it worked for me. below i added my code

Answer (score 0):

```
select replace(WBSElem, rtrim(ltrim(appProj)),  '') AS WBSElement,
replace(WBSElem+'#'+Descrip,'','')as Descrip, * from SAP_sFTP_DB.dbo.MMHE_PS_WBS where appProj='1.13T0117'
```

Due to White spaces the function did'nt work.Now its fine